# XSLT Substring not woring

Tags: substring, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, transformation, longest-substring

How to make XSLT substring-before second comma separate

for example the separator is ','

ex : Aban, aban, 22, 33

so the result should be

Aban, aban

and following numbers in other elements.